# jquery datatable columns from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Table has 5  columns to show

and I want to  get extra information id in rowData
when I added extra  `{data : id }` this gives error because table header count is less than cell data count so how can I access data id

```
 columns: [
            { data: 'sno' },
            { data: 'category' },
            { data: 'subcategory' },
            { data: 'netchange' },
            { data: 'stock' },
            { data: 'num' },
            { data: 'id' }  <---------------------------

     

        ],
```

I have already added id in response in server like this

```
$arr["id"] = $row["id"];
```

Comment: You may need to show more details - for example, the HTML used to contain the DataTable (e.g. the `<table>...</table>` HTML); (2) the full DataTable definition (or as much as is needed for a [MRE]); (3) a sample of your JSON, if you are using an Ajax data source - or a relevant data sample, otherwise.